# Using BeautifulSoup to search for a tag with certain attributes, but NOT fixed attribute values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML that I'm trying to search via beautifulsoup:

```
           <a href="/user_details?userid=**********">
```

The problem is I want to pull out all links with the above format, but the userid can change.  How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    link_href = link.get('href')
    if 'user_details' in link_href:
        # found match
        print link_href
```

do the trick?

We list all a (link) urls,
search for the string 'user_details' in each link,
if it's found - do work with the link.
If user_details matches something else, you could change it to something else.